# Multipke FB JS FQL query to get female family users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am totally new to FQL but uses FB JS API every day.

Is there an easy way to make two FQL queries, one for getting family members and another to get the female users of that result?

I can see that the FQL Multiquery is deprecated but you can do this still right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) and [family](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/family) table to run a query like -

```
SELECT uid, username FROM user where sex = 'female' and uid in ( select uid FROM family WHERE profile_id = me())
```